# Exporting Outlook 'previously emailed' contacts who aren't in the address book

Tags: microsoft-outlook, export, contacts, address-book

When sending an email to someone in Outlook it remembers their address, so if you try and send another email to them it'll prompt you with it - even if you haven't added them to the address book.

Is there any way of exporting those remembered addresses, or saving them to the address book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, since asking the question I've found they're referred to as auto-complete nicknames, and a number of utilities exist for migrating:

- [NK2Edit](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html), by Nirsoft
- [NK2.info](http://www.nk2.info/)

Answer (score 4):

Utilities not really necessary, it is simply a single file
See this [explanation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/copy-autocomplete-name-list-to-another-computer-HA001139451.aspx) for details

You only need to know the user name and the name of the associated pst file.